# Styleint-like Gulp plugin for JS files

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am looking for a plugin, that has the same functionality like a styleint Gulp plugin (displays errors in my CSS files). But I want this plugin to display errors in my Javascript files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried jslint?
http://www.jslint.com
also: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jslint